# Accessing multiple (?) values in CLIPS

Tags: artificial-intelligence, clips

Assume I have the following set of definstances which show the inputs and outputs of various stages of an electric circuit. I don't include all the classes and instances as I don't think it's relevant to my problem. I will include a photo that will help you understand how this problem works. [image]

Here input1 goes to adder A1 as both inputs. Input3 and input4 go to Π2 multiplier as inputs.

```
definstances facts(      
([command_10_inp1] of  command_data

    (clock 10)
    (object [input_1])
    (value 6))

([command_10_inp2] of  command_data

    (clock 10)
    (object [input_2])
    (value 4))

([command_10_inp3] of  command_data

    (clock 10)
    (object [input_3])
    (value 25))

([command_10_inp4] of  command_data

    (clock 10)
    (object [input_4])
    (value 12))

([command_1_inp1] of  command_data

    (clock 1)
    (object [input_1])
    (value 21))

([command_1_inp2] of  command_data

    (clock 1)
    (object [input_2])
    (value 28))

([command_1_inp3] of  command_data

    (clock 1)
    (object [input_3])
    (value 10))

([command_1_inp4] of  command_data

    (clock 1)
    (object [input_4])
    (value 25))

([command_2_inp1] of  command_data

    (clock 2)
    (object [input_1])
    (value 7))

([command_2_inp2] of  command_data

    (clock 2)
    (object [input_2])
    (value 25))

([command_2_inp3] of  command_data

    (clock 2)
    (object [input_3])
    (value 13))

([command_2_inp4] of  command_data

    (clock 2)
    (object [input_4])
    (value 15))

([command_3_inp1] of  command_data

    (clock 3)
    (object [input_1])
    (value 11))

([command_3_inp2] of  command_data

    (clock 3)
    (object [input_2])
    (value 17))

([command_3_inp3] of  command_data

    (clock 3)
    (object [input_3])
    (value 24))

([command_3_inp4] of  command_data

    (clock 3)
    (object [input_4])
    (value 31))

([command_4_inp1] of  command_data

    (clock 4)
    (object [input_1])
    (value 18))

([command_4_inp2] of  command_data

    (clock 4)
    (object [input_2])
    (value 11))

([command_4_inp3] of  command_data

    (clock 4)
    (object [input_3])
    (value 28))

([command_4_inp4] of  command_data

    (clock 4)
    (object [input_4])
    (value 21))

([command_5_inp1] of  command_data

    (clock 5)
    (object [input_1])
    (value 25))

([command_5_inp2] of  command_data

    (clock 5)
    (object [input_2])
    (value 24))

([command_5_inp3] of  command_data

    (clock 5)
    (object [input_3])
    (value 30))

([command_5_inp4] of  command_data

    (clock 5)
    (object [input_4])
    (value 10))

([command_6_inp1] of  command_data

    (clock 6)
    (object [input_1])
    (value 12))

([command_6_inp2] of  command_data

    (clock 6)
    (object [input_2])
    (value 19))

([command_6_inp3] of  command_data

    (clock 6)
    (object [input_3])
    (value 11))

([command_6_inp4] of  command_data

    (clock 6)
    (object [input_4])
    (value 19))

([command_7_inp1] of  command_data

    (clock 7)
    (object [input_1])
    (value 1))

([command_7_inp2] of  command_data

    (clock 7)
    (object [input_2])
    (value 31))

([command_7_inp3] of  command_data

    (clock 7)
    (object [input_3])
    (value 7))

([command_7_inp4] of  command_data

    (clock 7)
    (object [input_4])
    (value 22))

([command_8_inp1] of  command_data

    (clock 8)
    (object [input_1])
    (value 0))

([command_8_inp2] of  command_data

    (clock 8)
    (object [input_2])
    (value 31))

([command_8_inp3] of  command_data

    (clock 8)
    (object [input_3])
    (value 3))

([command_8_inp4] of  command_data

    (clock 8)
    (object [input_4])
    (value 23))

([command_9_inp1] of  command_data

    (clock 9)
    (object [input_1])
    (value 31))

([command_9_inp2] of  command_data

    (clock 9)
    (object [input_2])
    (value 1))

([command_9_inp3] of  command_data

    (clock 9)
    (object [input_3])
    (value 6))

([command_9_inp4] of  command_data

    (clock 9)
    (object [input_4])
    (value 8))


([reading_10_m1] of  reading_data

    (clock 10)
    (object [m1])
    (value 12))

([reading_10_m2] of  reading_data

    (clock 10)
    (object [m2])
    (value 31))

([reading_10_m3] of  reading_data

    (clock 10)
    (object [m3])
    (value 12))

([reading_10_out] of  reading_data

    (clock 10)
    (object [out1])
    (value 28))

([reading_1_m1] of  reading_data

    (clock 1)
    (object [m1])
    (value 10))

([reading_1_m2] of  reading_data

    (clock 1)
    (object [m2])
    (value 24))

([reading_1_m3] of  reading_data

    (clock 1)
    (object [m3])
    (value 26))

([reading_1_out] of  reading_data

    (clock 1)
    (object [out1])
    (value 18))

([reading_2_m1] of  reading_data

    (clock 2)
    (object [m1])
    (value 0))

([reading_2_m2] of  reading_data

    (clock 2)
    (object [m2])
    (value 0))

([reading_2_m3] of  reading_data

    (clock 2)
    (object [m3])
    (value 3))

([reading_2_out] of  reading_data

    (clock 2)
    (object [out1])
    (value 3))

([reading_3_m1] of  reading_data

    (clock 3)
    (object [m1])
    (value 22))

([reading_3_m2] of  reading_data

    (clock 3)
    (object [m2])
    (value 6))

([reading_3_m3] of  reading_data

    (clock 3)
    (object [m3])
    (value 8))

([reading_3_out] of  reading_data

    (clock 3)
    (object [out1])
    (value 14))

([reading_4_m1] of  reading_data

    (clock 4)
    (object [m1])
    (value 4))

([reading_4_m2] of  reading_data

    (clock 4)
    (object [m2])
    (value 12))

([reading_4_m3] of  reading_data

    (clock 4)
    (object [m3])
    (value 12))

([reading_4_out] of  reading_data

    (clock 4)
    (object [out1])
    (value 0))

([reading_5_m1] of  reading_data

    (clock 5)
    (object [m1])
    (value 18))

([reading_5_m2] of  reading_data

    (clock 5)
    (object [m2])
    (value 16))

([reading_5_m3] of  reading_data

    (clock 5)
    (object [m3])
    (value 12))

([reading_5_out] of  reading_data

    (clock 5)
    (object [out1])
    (value 12))

([reading_6_m1] of  reading_data

    (clock 6)
    (object [m1])
    (value 8))

([reading_6_m2] of  reading_data

    (clock 6)
    (object [m2])
    (value 24))

([reading_6_m3] of  reading_data

    (clock 6)
    (object [m3])
    (value 17))

([reading_6_out] of  reading_data

    (clock 6)
    (object [out1])
    (value 9))

([reading_7_m1] of  reading_data

    (clock 7)
    (object [m1])
    (value 2))

([reading_7_m2] of  reading_data

    (clock 7)
    (object [m2])
    (value 0))

([reading_7_m3] of  reading_data

    (clock 7)
    (object [m3])
    (value 26))

([reading_7_out] of  reading_data

    (clock 7)
    (object [out1])
    (value 26))

([reading_8_m1] of  reading_data

    (clock 8)
    (object [m1])
    (value 0))

([reading_8_m2] of  reading_data

    (clock 8)
    (object [m2])
    (value 0))

([reading_8_m3] of  reading_data

    (clock 8)
    (object [m3])
    (value 0))

([reading_8_out] of  reading_data

    (clock 8)
    (object [out1])
    (value 0))

([reading_9_m1] of  reading_data

    (clock 9)
    (object [m1])
    (value 30))

([reading_9_m2] of  reading_data

    (clock 9)
    (object [m2])
    (value 30))

([reading_9_m3] of  reading_data

    (clock 9)
    (object [m3])
    (value 12))

([reading_9_out] of  reading_data

    (clock 9)
    (object [out1])
    (value 28))
)
)
```

By using the following assert rules I can get a list of all the facts along with which input or sensor they belong to :

```
(defrule assert-inputs
    (object (is-a command_data) (clock ?clock) (object ?object) (value ?value))
    =>
    (assert (fact ?clock ?object ?value)))

(defrule assert-outputs
    (object (is-a reading_data) (clock ?clock) (object ?object) (value ?value))
    =>
    (assert (fact ?clock ?object ?value)))
```

I want to somehow be able to handle all inputs in the facts and be able to see what happens after they pass an adder or a multiplier. I managed to do this for A1 because it takes as input only input1 two times like this :

```
(defrule check_a1
    (fact ?clock ?object ?value)
    (test (eq ?object [input_1]))
    =>
    (assert (fact ?clock [m1t] (mod(+ ?value ?value)(** 2 5)))))
```

However Π2 multiplier takes as input two different values input3 and input4. By using the following I can manage to print all the facts that are either of input3 or input4. The problem is I don't know how to use them in the same manner as I used them above when they were only one since for every new fact I want to create I have two different values. Is there an easy way to access these values? I tried to bind them to a different variable and access them like nth$ 1 and nth$ 2 but I couldn't make it work.

```
 (defrule check_p2
    (fact ?clock ?object ?value)
    (test (or (eq ?object [input_3]) (eq ?object [input_4])))
    =>
    (printout t ?clock " " ?object " " ?value crlf))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to grab two different facts with the same clock value, different values, and objects [input_3] and [input_4], use this rule:

```
(defrule check_p2
   (fact ?clock [input_3] ?value3)
   (fact ?clock [input_4] ?value4)
   =>
   ; Your action here
)
```

Comment: Mr Gary you are a lifesaver! Is there an easy way to store my results as integers instead of floats?

Comment: You can use either the integer or round function to convert an integer to a float.